# Python: Compare data against the 95th percentile of a running window dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, large-data

I have a large DataFrame of thousands of rows but only 2 columns.  The 2 columns are of the below format:

| Dt | Val |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 10.5 |
| 2020-01-01 | 11.2 |
| 2020-01-01 | 10.9 |
| 2020-01-03 | 11.3 |
| 2020-01-05 | 12.0 |

The first column is date and the second column is a value.  For each date, there may be zero, one or more values.

**What I need to do is the following:**  Compute the 95th percentile based on the 30 days that just past and see if the current value is above or below that 95th percentile value.  There must however be a minimum of 50 values available for the past 30 days.

For example, if a record has date "2020-12-01" and value "10.5", then I need to first see how many values are there available for the date range 2020-11-01 to 2020-11-30.  If there are at least 50 values available over that date range, then I will want to compute the 95th percentile of those values and compare 10.5 against that.  If 10.5 is greater than the 95th percentile value, then the result for that record is "Above Threshold".  If 10.5 is less than the 95th percentile value, then the result for that record is "Below Threshold".  If there are less than 50 values over the date range 2020-11-01 to 2020-11-30, then the result for that record is "Insufficient Data".

I would like to avoid running a loop if possible as it may be expensive from a resource and time perspective to loop through thousands of records to process them one by one.  I hope someone can advise of a simple(r) python / pandas solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rolling on DatetimeIndex to get the number of values available and the 95th percentile in the last 30 days. Here is an example with 3 days rolling window:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'val':[1,2,3,4,5,6]},
                  index = [datetime.date(2020,10,1), datetime.date(2020,10,1), datetime.date(2020,10,2),
                           datetime.date(2020,10,3), datetime.date(2020,10,3), datetime.date(2020,10,4)])

df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)

df['number_of_values'] = df.rolling('3D').count()
df['rolling_percentile'] = df.rolling('3D')['val'].quantile(0.9, interpolation='nearest')
```

Then you can simply do your comparison:

```
# Above Threshold
(df['val']>df['rolling_percentile'])&(df['number_of_values']>=50)

# Below Threshold
(df['val']>df['rolling_percentile'])&(df['number_of_values']>=50)

# Insufficient Data
df['number_of_values']<50
```

To remove the current date, `close` argument would not work for more than one row on a day, so maybe use the rolling apply:

```
def f(x, metric):
    x = x[x.index!=x.index[-1]]
    if metric == 'count':
        return len(x)
    elif metric == 'percentile':
        return x.quantile(0.9, interpolation='nearest')
    else:
        return np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'val':[1,2,3,4,5,6]},
                  index = [datetime.date(2020,10,1), datetime.date(2020,10,1), datetime.date(2020,10,2),
                           datetime.date(2020,10,3), datetime.date(2020,10,3), datetime.date(2020,10,4)])
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
df['count'] = df.rolling('3D')['val'].apply(f, args = ('count',))
df['percentile'] = df.rolling('3D')['val'].apply(f, args = ('percentile',))
```

```
          val   count   percentile
2020-10-01  1   0.0  NaN
2020-10-01  2   0.0  NaN
2020-10-02  3   2.0  2.0
2020-10-03  4   3.0  3.0
2020-10-03  5   3.0  3.0
2020-10-04  6   3.0  5.0
```

Comment: You beat me :). I think you should add `closed='left'` to the `rolling` arguments (OP want's to exclude the current date)?

Comment: Thank you for the code. I tried it and it generally works, but it still has a small issue.  Even with`closed='left'` in the rolling argument, it does not exclude all of the current date's values.  It only exclude the current value.  For example, in the code provided, number_of_values for the first 2020-10-03 record is 3 but number_of_values for the second 2020-10-03 record is 4.  This is because the second 2020-10-03 record included the first 2020-10-03 record.  Is there any way to make the rolling window exclude all current date records?

Comment: @RichardWong that is a good point. I can't think of an easy way as you need the percentile data, which does not allow any attempt to aggregate the data to get one row for each date. for loop is always a solution and it could be almost as efficient as rolling(). Or you can use rolling to aggregate the count for each date and use a for loop to parse the percentile part.

Comment: @RichardWong See the updated version above

Comment: @ZLi The updated version works perfectly.  Thank you!